# Linux file system that ages off older files when partition is full

Tags: linux, filesystems

I am wondering if there is a file system equivalent to a round-robin database, which for a fixed size, ages off the oldest files. It is pretty easy to implement with a simple cron job, which I have, but I assume it is a problem many people have and there is perhaps something better. I wish to set a fixed-size partition, or pool, in which older files are automatically removed, or aged-off, when the pool is full. A type of circular-buffer that would use the space left by the oldest file for the new ones, whilst preserving file integrity.

My cron solution compares disk usage to a threshold and recursively removes the oldest file until disk usage is again under the threshold. It is not perfect because one can't guarantee the threshold is low enough that it isn't overtaken between two cron iterations. It also doesn't maximize the use of the storage space because of the threshold value which tends to be predictive in nature (how much can I fill in one minute, between two iterations of crond). Two shortcomings I am hoping to improve upon.

I am looking for a more elegant solution, akin to how the round-robin database (http://linux.die.net/man/1/rrdtool) handles this transparently, but for file systems.

Comment: what about overloading the mv command to perform the verification and deletion (as required) before moving files into the partition?

Comment: providing an alternate method of achieving the goal, hopefully triggering some useful comments.

Comment: any merit in considering logrotate? I believe you can write rules for any kind of files, but how to guarantee it runs in a timely fashion (when needed) to store more files.

Comment: You aren't looking for a filesystem. Filesystems excel at storing files in a resilient fashion, with no other goals. What you want are some other userland tools to unlink old files. Or perhaps you should just use Amazon S3 with a bucket expiration policy.

Comment: I disagree. Filesystems are built with various features. Some perform de-deplucation, some allow distributed storage. My need is for one that will maximize the use the fixed size storage it has, and intelligently use the space left by removing the oldest file to store the new ones.

Comment: I agree with user153222, above; `tmpfs` is an excellent example of a file system that most definitely does **not** store information in a resilient manner, but is very useful in certain circumstances because of what it does do.  You use a tool to serve a need, and I can easily conceive needs which a ring-buffered file system would well serve.  I am by no means sure this is a bad question, and I hope it doesn't get closed.

Comment: Disagree if you like, but all the examples you give fulfill a filesystem's chief goal of **storing** files, not deleting files.

Comment: Are rhe files all the same size? Do you have control over when/where/how the files are written? Is it a few huge files or a trillion small files, or a mixture (important for performance considerations)?  I think you said its a ramdisk?  Does it need to be?

Comment: No, sizes depend on network events which I don't control, and so is the rate of filling. It does need to be a RAMDISK for my problem, but the problem is the same if I could use another media or a larger media. A lot of tools offer to age off based on fixed time criteria (logrotate, Amazon S3 bucket expiration); rather, I need something which ages off based on fixed storage size, in order to retain my files as long as I possibly can. I don't wish files to age off based on time if I have room to store them. Conversely if the storage if full, I don't particularly care older files vanish...

Comment: Here's a helpful link (to Wikipedia): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-structured_file_system

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There exist many HSM ([Hierarchical Storage Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_storage_management)) systems, mainly aimed at SAN systems. These migrate files from faster disks, to slower disks, to tape as their last-access-time becomes older. You might like to seek out one of these, if you have a SAN. Most of the ones I know of are commercial licenses though, such as the IBM Tivoli HSM that we use. You might like to take a look at [OHSM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ohsm/) though.

If you just want to delete old files, then a simple cron job such as `find /data -atime +30 -exec rm {} \;` will delete files that have not been accessed in a certain amount of time (but make sure the filesystem is not mounted with the `noatime` option!) This would be highly risky, though, unless you had a good online backup system.

Comment: this is pretty much what I have now, but not quite sufficient to guarantee the filesystem does not fill between two cron iterations

Comment: I would say that you're doing it the wrong way.  Either add a lot of disk to the filesystem, increase the frequency of your cron, or find some other way.  If you find yourself needing to delete an unspecified amount of data regularly like this there's probably a problem with whatever is filling the filesystem.
I take it that the filesystem in question is a temporary one; in that case, the processes writing to it should be written to clean up after themselves better, and you should probably increase the size of the filesystem.

Comment: I appreciate the comment Steve, but I have a legitimate need for a file system that will retain files in a "best effort" kind of way. Under normal conditions, the files are removed periodically by a remote process. In the case of a communications outage, I wish the pool to retain as much as possible, aging off whatever falls off the top, retaining the most recent files up to the capacity of the pool. I am looking for an automated way this can be done, just like it happens in rrdtool. My alternate solutions are ok, but then I need to set a threshold which ensures I do not fill the pool too fast

Comment: So - the filesystem is used a bit like a queue, and when it fills, you'd rather lose the oldest entry than the newest?  That makes sense.  However, this is really something that should be managed by the application writing to it...
I would say that you should (a) increase the FS size so the risk of a problem is lower, and (b) you can probably write a simple perl script to query FS free space, and delete files in reverse order of age until free space > X.  This might be harder if the directory structure is more complex though.

Comment: Exactly like a queue yes. Cannot increase FS (it is a RAMDISK). I already have the equivalent of the perl script you mention as mentioned above, but am looking for a more elegant solution if one exists. Directory structure is flat in this case, but if such filesystem existed, I would hope the queue could still work even in complex hierarchies.

Comment: HSM is a good recommendation worth investigating further. I cannot upvote it but would.

Comment: OHSM may be a valid solution though I was not able to verify from the documentation. The idea would be to relocate older files to /dev/null when the high-cost storage fills up. Not sure it can be done, will investigate.

Comment: more like a circular buffer than a queue, really. The new data would overwrite the old data in the partition, maintaining file integrity.

Comment: anyone with experience with LogFS? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-structured_file_system It seems to be close to what I am looking for.

Answer (score -1):

I can only hope that there is no such file system in existence (cursory searches don't seem to return much of interest). This sounds like the plot for a horrible dream...

Anyway, I presume the short answer is: Nothing like this exists.

And I do dearly hope that is true :(

---

As for your cron ... if you are only worried about overlapping crons... Use a lock file. Then your only worry is, "Can my *application* fill this filesystem before cron runs again?"

Comment: Not worried about overlapping crons, but am worried about filling the partition before the cron daemon runs again.

Comment: horrible dream is not a valid comment in my mind: rrdtool exits for a reason. And imagine you need to store files instead of data in a database... Not that far fetched.

Comment: interesting how some people choose to focus on second-guessing my need rather than recommending solutions... rrdtool has the capability to age off older data using a moving window analogy, an retains a fixed size. This is how I wish the partition to behave. I have no need for SQL features.

Comment: The second guessing of need comes from years of people bringing us XY problems.  Not nesessarily the case here, but since you dont describe what you are actually doing we tend to assume thats the case for unusual requirements. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Very good, thanks for the link. I don't think it is the case here, I describe my need first, the best I can.  I also provide the solution that I have and the two shortcomings I am trying to overcome. I really don't understand why some would flag this with "minimum understanding"-> clearly not the case in my mind. I also disagree with your statement I don't describe what I am doing. I provide the use case in the comments above.

Comment: @user153222 I agree its probably not the case here.  But it happens so often people sometimes assume that is the case.